# Run program on mac os with Python fails

Tags: python, macos, macos-sierra

I am running a Houdini application with Python on Sierra 10.12.2:

```
subprocess.Popen( '/Applications/Houdini 15.5.673/Houdini Apprentice.app/Contents/MacOS/happrentice'  )
```

Houdini begin to launch but an error appears and its fail to run. If I run application usual way bu clicking an icon it launches fine.

Beginning of error report

```
Process:               happrentice [649]
Path:                  /Applications/Houdini 15.5.673/Houdini Apprentice.app/Contents/MacOS/happrentice
Identifier:            com.sidefx.HoudiniApprentice
Version:               15.5.673 (15.5.673)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           happrentice [649]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-01-06 15:40:07.702 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.2 (16C67)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5222C238-807C-7D74-6CFC-4C701B2E0D86


Time Awake Since Boot: 210 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
terminating with uncaught exception of type HOM_Error
abort() called
```

Comment: What happens if you try the same thing from a Terminal window, by typing `'/Applications/Houdini 15.5.673/Houdini Apprentice.app/Contents/MacOS/happrentice'`?

Comment: It also crashes with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the program is designed to be run by `LaunchServices`, not directly. Try using the `open` command to run it.

```
subprocess.Popen( ['open', '/Applications/Houdini 15.5.673/Houdini Apprentice.app'] )
```

Comment: Same result — crashes.

Comment: That's very strange, because this should emulate exactly what happens when you double-click on the application icon.

Comment: Exactly! So the issue is so wired that i have no idea what to try more.

Comment: How are you running the Python script? From a Terminal window or something else?

Comment: In a two ways: from terminal window and right click on python file > Open with > Python launcher app

Comment: What happens if you type `open '/Applications/Houdini 15.5.673/Houdini Apprentice.app'` in the Terminal?

Comment: Houdini also crashes!

Comment: I'm at a loss. There's a forum at sidefx.com, maybe someone there can help.

Comment: Me either :) I did not find the answer on sidefx forum also.
Thank you Barmar for your help!